Is there any way we can wait in the execution until cucumber.json and cucumber.html files generated and loaded with content?
I tried to copy cucumber.json and cucumber.html files from target folder to other folder which is suffixed with date and time. I am able to copy to destination folder but cucumber.html file and cucumber.json are empty in most of the times. Is there any way we can wait until cucumber.json and cucumber.html files fully loaded with content?.
Tried:
In @afterall annotation, i tried to copy cucumber.json and cucumber.html file from target folder to other folder.
Expected:
cucumber.json and cucumber.html file has to be copied with full content.
Actual:
Empty files are being copied most of the cases.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/79006457/3945473

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
